# How do I detect an app has been downloaded in China?

Tags: ios, app-store

I am looking for a reliable mechanism to find out if my application has been downloaded in China. What are my options?

There is an `appStoreReceiptURL` method on `NSBundle` which points to a DER  encoded receipt file. I understand this receipt may also contain the country of the App Store where it was downloaded. Does anyone know how reliable that information is?

Are there other options?

Comment: I am not sure what your needs are. I assume you want to do some different behavior within your app for China Vs rest of the world then why not use CLLocation manager?

Comment: I don't want to ask location permission. Also, people could disallow that.

Comment: Here's another sneaky way, how about mobileCountryCode using CTTelephonyNetworkInfo?

Comment: That is a great fallback for phones.

Answer (score 2):

For iPhones you can use this

```
CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *network_Info = [CTTelephonyNetworkInfo new];
CTCarrier *carrier = network_Info.subscriberCellularProvider;

NSLog(@"country code is: %@", carrier.mobileCountryCode);

//will return the actual country code
NSLog(@"country code is: %@", carrier.isoCountryCode);
```

Comment: CTTelephonyNetworkInfo is mostly deprecated...